# How to get images of whole blog in option page of wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to get all images sources of the blog in the options page of plugin and i am making a plugin option page as follows ..Plz look in to it ..

```
public function add_plugin_page(){  
                add_options_page('Settings Admin', 'Plugin_options', 'manage_options', 'test-setting-admin', array($this, 'create_admin_page'));
            }
```

Following code is for my plugin option page

```
public function create_admin_page(){
        ?>
    <div class="wrap">

    <?php screen_icon(); ?>

    <form action="options.php" method="post" id="<?php echo $plugin_id; ?>_options_form" name="<?php echo $plugin_id; ?>_options_form">

    <?php settings_fields($plugin_id.'_options'); ?>

    <h2>kk Plugin Options &raquo; Settings</h2>

   <table border="1" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFCC; margin-top:22px"  width="25%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:8px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;color:#666;"><h3>Blog Id:</h3></td>
        <td><p><?php echo$abc?></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:8px;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;color:#666;"><h3>API Key:</h3></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="kkpo_quote" value="<?php echo get_option('kkpo_quote'); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>

</table>
   <div id="mainCHImage" style="position:relative;height:'.$imgHeight.'px;width:'.$width.'px;">
         <img id="paletlyIcon" style="position:absolute;left:'.$imgWidth.'px;top:'.$imgHeight.'px;z-index:9999;cursor:pointer;background:none;border:none;" src="http://Images/favIcon.png" onclick="get_images()">'.   
        <img style="background:none;border:none;"></div>


    </form>

</div>
    <?php
    }
```

$abc is variable in which i want all image sources ..For that i have written a separate function

```
public function get_images(){
    if(is_single() || is_page() || is_home()||!is_admin() ){  
    global $post; 
    global $wpdb;

    $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
    $images = array();

         foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {      
         $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
                 $abc=($images);
                 echo $abc;
                 }

    }


}
```

But i am getting error

```
ReferenceError: get_images is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

get_images();
```

I have added that function in my construct i.e.

```
add_action('IMages_grab', array(&$this, 'get_images'));
add_filter('IMages_grab', array(&$this, 'get_images'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude , your code is wrong on so many levels ! 
(and I am expressing only My own opinion here . )

1. you have  `$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );` but you did not defined `$query_images_arg`   ( fix by defining arguments )
2. you are constructing some kind of admin menu, but then you put the condition of `!is_admin()`  which will null everything ( fix by deciding / defining where it operates )
3. you have many syntax errors like `echo$abc?` ( fix to `echo $abc` )

   3.1. $abc is supposed to be an array ? then you can not even use echo but `print_r($abc);`
4. you are using the `settings APi` , which is serialized array , and then you call single options like `echo get_option('kkpo_quote');`  ( fix decide which method to use )
5. this is the most important one , why on earth would one want to get ALL the images of a whole website into an array , and further more , echo it ?? can you imagine what will happen with a site that has 10,000 images _ or even only 300 ?

Now , your code is clearly some kind of an attempt or an exercise  in cut & paste plugin development . and to give a good answer will mean you will have to better explain your intentions, but you can start with fixing what I have wrote in the above , and not complete, list ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most of @ObmerkKronen Answer, but with point `5`. Which is the core of Question, in my opinion.

Yes, it's valid to want an array with *all* posts (and attachments are a *post type*). And a 10K array may not be that big depending of how it's used.

The following example displays an Admin Notice with links to all images in the Media Library. [Consult the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/) to know the functions used here. Should be fairly easy to adapt this to a plugin's option page.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'get_all_images_so_15985067' );

function get_all_images_so_15985067() 
{
    // get all images
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    );
    $_attachments = get_posts( $args );

    // no images found, do nothing
    if ( empty( $_attachments ) )
        return;

    // build array only with IDs
    $attachments = array();
    foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
        $attachments[ $val->ID ] = $_attachments[ $key ];
    }

    // print thumbnail links
    echo '<div class="updated">';
    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_link( 
            $att_id, 
            'thumbnail', 
            false, 
            false, 
            $attachment->post_title 
        ) . "<br>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: (hehe , we meet again.. ) Note that my pseudo - objection was not to the use of the array by itself, but to the fact that OP wants to echo it to the screen